# Storing nested lists

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I really need some assistance so I'm trying so freaking hard to store a str in a list inside a list and this will not freaking work. The code I have written makes perfect sense to me. Can someone please give me some guidance here. I'm desperate. I continously get errors on at line 30 `myArrayList.get(index).add(newClassObj);`

suggesting >>

```
          at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
          at myClass.main(myClass.java:30)


public class myCLass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

     ArrayList<LinkedList<myCLass>>
     myArrayList = new ArrayList<LinkedList<MyClass>>(26);

     inFile file = new inFile();
     file.inFile("myfile.txt");
        while(inFile.hasNext())
        {
            String str = inFile.next();
            char ch = str.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            char ch2 = 'A';
            int index = (int)ch - (int)ch2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
                myArrayList.add(new LinkedList<MyClass>());
            myClass newClassObj = new myClass(str);
            myArrayList.get(index).add(newClassObj);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? where is the stack trace ?

Comment: `"...and this will not freaking work."` -- How does it not freaking work?  What error(s) do you get?  What is in "myfile.txt"?  What output do you expect?  What output do you get?  Please read about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Please don't try to add information in comments.  Instead edit your question to add more information/clarification.

Comment: The errors I'm getting is at       'java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
 at CountWords.main(MyClass.java:30)'
I'm sorry, just becoming very frustrated with this program. I am trying to store my str into the correct location of my one of my link lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're ever making your lists. You have a list that has 26 slots, but you're never filling those slots with a list.

I don't know what this `infile` is so I just used `java.util.Scanner` for testing. I also don't see this original MyClass class, so I'm just adding the Strings. Yours is a little different, but the algorithm is the same.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>(26);
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            list.add(new LinkedList<String>());
        }
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String next = sc.next();
            char c = next.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            int index = c - 'A';
            list.get(index).add(next);
        }
        // let's test it by looking at all the H words
        System.out.println(list.get(7));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
C:\files\j>javac MyClass.java

C:\files\j>java MyClass
[have, he, his, her, him, how]
```

Comment: When I try to .add(str) it says no suitable method found for add(STRING)

Comment: That's because you have a `LinkedList<myClass>` and I have a `LinkedList<String>` - if you're adding Strings, add Strings. If you're adding myClasses, add myClasses.

Comment: So right after I posted that I figured that out lol; however, its printing out what I think are the addresses of myClass. like "myClass@454bff" or w.e

Comment: You need to override your `toString()` method to print the data being passed into its constructor, or loop over the values and print the string directly.

Comment: I do not have access to the class for this assignment :/

Comment: Then you'll have to loop over it. `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); for(MyClass c : list.get(7)) { sb.append(c.getData()).append(" "); } System.out.println(sb);` Replace the `getData()` with however you access the string you passed in.

Comment: Oh wow haha. There is no simpler way? I have nothing what you have typed makes any sense to me haha I'm very foreign to string builder

Comment: What does the assignment specifically say? What is the requirement?

Comment: I don't necessarily have to print out the contents of anything right way; however, I am trying to print the first word(str) in the first linkedList(0) to to make sure that word is being stored in the correct linkedList (index). So I am trying to print out any link list to see if the correct words are being stored in the correct linked list before moving forward. because this is a key part. I feel like I have most of the code but I'm missing something but I can not figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Before you can call `myArrayList.get(index).add(newClassObj);`, you must make sure that `index` < `myArrayList.size()`. Otherwise you'll get an index out of bounds exception.

Your `myArrayList`'s size is 0, since you never add anything to it. Initializing the capacity to 26 doesn't add 26 elements to the list. It doesn't add any elements to the list.

If you wish your list to have 26 elements, you should initialize it properly :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    myArrayList.add(new LinkedList<MyClass>());
```

Comment: I don't think that will happen since he is initializing it with 26 and as i count there are 26 alphabets. I think the main problem is he hasn't initialized all the LinkedList inside.

Comment: @StackFlowed a **capacity** of 26 is not the same as a **size** of 26. He is initializing it with a capacity of 26 - but a size of 0.

Comment: @StackFlowed An ArrayList is not an array. It doesn't get initialized with 26 null references. It is initialized to an empty ArrayList.

Comment: so if index < myArrayList.Size() THAN myArrayList.get(index).add(newClassObj);

Comment: @helperhex However, `index < myArrayList.Size()` will always be false, unless you add an initialization as in my answer.

Comment: I edited it. So is my code below the if statement still correct? or do I have logic errors in my lines below the if statement

Comment: @helperhex The for loop should be before the while loop. When you put it in the while loop you are adding new 26 elements in each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: @Eran One more question, thank you for the help by the way. How can I so a system.out.print to check to see what is being stored inside each LinkedList. I am no sure what to print out.

Comment: @helperhex You should override `toString()` in your `MyClass` class and return whatever String you wish to be printed for each `MyClass` object. Once you do that, `System.out.println(myArrayList)` will print all the elements in all the lists.

Comment: I am not able to access the class for this assignment :/